# Django form throws select valid choice

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have read every answer for this question but none of them solved my problem completely. I hope someone can help me understand what is wrong in my code. I have a field in my model and I want all the values in that field to be displayed in a dropdown in my form. I was able to achieve that but when I try to save, it says "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." Any help would be greatly appreciated.

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    Product = models.ForeignKey("Product", related_name = "Items")
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    Tag = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    items = Item.objects.values_list('Name', flat=True)
    item_choices = [(item, item) for item in items]
    Name = forms.ModelChoiceField(items, widget=forms.Select())
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['Name', 'Tag']
```

views.py

```
def newknowledgebase(request):
    itemformset = modelformset_factory(Item, form=ItemForm, extra=2) 
    items = itemformset(queryset=Item.objects.none(), prefix='items', )
    if request.method=='POST':
        items = itemformset(request.POST, queryset=Item.objects.none(), prefix='items', )
        item = request.POST.get('items')
        for form in items:
            form.fields['Name'].choices = [(item, item)]
        if items.is_valid():
            items.save()

    context = {
        'items':items,
    }
    return render(request, 'newknowledgebase.html', context )
```

html file

```
<div id="items" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                {{ items }}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: What values do the select box options have in the rendered HTML? Also, try to name your form & model field's using lower case. Keep the titlecase & camel casing to your class names; https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: The select box option lists all the item names as expected. If there are 10 items, all the names for those items are listed in the select box. And thank you for your suggestion, I will follow that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Name = forms.ChoiceField(item_choices, widget=forms.Select())
```

Comment: getting any error or no value displayed. can you please share the code?

Comment: It was my fault, your answer worked! thank you so much.